# Topological spaces having countable dense sets

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space such that every non-empty open subset of $X$ can be written as a countable union of  disjoint open sets , then does $X$ contain a countable set (in set-theoretic sense) which is dense in $X$   (like $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ with usual topology) ? If it is not true then does there exist any sufficient condition which ensures that a topological space contains a countable dense set ?

Comment: If $U$ is a set, then $U=\cup\{U\}$. So your condition in trivially satisfied. Not all topological spaces have countable dense sets. Those that do are called [*separable*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSeparable_space&ei=TaPvUv2mEcaIygHU4oGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNGCIrm4rO-PiFsc_ADiTM_6JHHAmw&bvm=bv.60444564,d.aWc).

Comment: Maybe you wanted connected sets?

Comment: You might want to mark this as answered if you don't have any further questions

Answer (score 1):

As David notes, your proposed criterion is trivially satisfied for every subset of ever set. I suspect you mean being second-countable, ie having a countable base. Having a countable dense subset is known as being seperable.

Second-countable implies seperable (by virtue of the base being an example of a countae dense subset) but the reverse implication does not hold. The lower limit topology on R is seperable but not second countable. These two properties are equivalent on a metric space however. Take a countable dense subset and consider the balls of radius {1/n}. Then this forms a countable basis.