# Can any subset of the unit interval be decomposed into a countable number of everywhere-dense sets?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have an uncountable set $U$ of real numbers in $[0, 1)$.

I would like to decompose it into a family of subsets $S_i$ such that:

- Each of $S_i$ is a dense interval, i.e. is everywhere dense in $[min(S_i), max(S_i))$
- Each of $S_i$ is maximal in this sense, i.e. adding any number from $U \backslash S_i$  would make it stop being everywhere dense in $[min(S_i), max(S_i))$

Is it true that, for any set $U$, there exists such a decomposition into a countable number of subsets $S_i$?

(I've looked at some similar questions, e.g. [Topological spaces having countable dense sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662037/topological-spaces-having-countable-dense-sets) but didn't find anything directly addressing my question, and my knowledge of topology is very basic and is not good enough to know what else to search for)

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question. I mean everywhere dense, but in an interval

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that this is clearly false: the Cantor set is uncountable and nowhere dense, i.e. it can not be decomposed into everywhere-dense subsets.

(which raises a separate question: is there a name for the property "can be decomposed into a countable number of everywhere dense sets"?)